# .htaccess - Passing Multiple Variables to RewriteRule with RewriteConditions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Searched and am not able to find any other question similar.

I have these example lines in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^service=rp$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/redirect/?service=rp&token=$1&time=$2 [R=301,L]
```

However, it is not passing the variables to the RewriteRule.  There are three variables:

service, token, time

Looked at other answers and it was mentioned to use $1, $2, and $3 to capture the variables in the original URL but it doesn't seem to be passing properly.

Comment: Seem you need to figure out how the regular expresions work. `$1..$n` - are the references to the suggestion's groups which can be specified via brace within the RegExp. Have look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression, for instance.

Comment: It is impossible to answer to this question without you specifying the syntax of the incoming requests to be rewritten.

Comment: If you only need to _preserve_ specified GET arguments however, then just consider the `QSA` flag the rewriting module offers (read the documentation for that...).

Comment: Apparently I am still doing something incorrectly.  I changed the RewriteRule line to -- RewriteRule /test.php?$1 [QSA,R=301,L] so I could see the variables passed in.  Upon doing so, it redirects me to test.php?service=rp --- but it still is not passing the other two variables in.